# System.Security.Cryptography namespace not available in .NET framework 5.4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-framework-version

Please help guys.

I created a new project `Class Library (Package)` in Visual Studio 2015.
I want to use this project in MVC 6 project.
Now it complains that Cryptography does not exist in System.Security even after I have added reference to System.Security.

Even if I have the code directly to the MVC 6 project it's still complaining.

[image]

I am not sure whether it has to do with the .NET Framework version because it also shows that this namespace is not available in framework 5.4

[image]

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: That class is not in .NET Core yet (might never come), so you need to switch to an explicit encryption provider, DES or others. Meanwhile, please upgrade to RC2 from http://dot.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much guys for your help.
I managed to get it working by removing the `dotnet5.4` framework from the `project.json` file. See screenshot below

[image]

This framework get added automatically when you create a new project, even if you select `framework 4.5.1`.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If this is RC2 then pull in netstandard1.5

```
var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
```

IIRC net5.4 isn't correct anymore and it also looks like you are multi targetting so maybe something like:

```
#if NETSTANDARD1_5
  var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create();
#else
 var aes = Rijndael.Create();
#endif
```